# How do I run a Core Lightning Node on top of Bitcoin Knots?

Tags: lightning-network, client, core-lightning, bitcoin-knots

Recently, [Giacommo Zucco](https://www.giacomozucco.com/) [mentioned that he runs Bitcoin Knots](https://youtu.be/pDHx8XyIsxA?t=4926) instead of Bitcoin Core. As far as I know, he is an experienced Lightning user and so there must be a way in which he runs his lightning node on top of [Bitcoin Knots](https://github.com/bitcoinknots/bitcoin/releases) instead of Bitcoin Core. I myself have been running a nonrouting [Core Lightning](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/getting-started/getting-started/installation.md) node on Debian and Ubuntu for a couple of years. Is running Core Lightning with Bitcoin Knots so seamless as with Bitcoin Core? Does it require any tweaks or special configuration in `.lightning/bitcoin/config`?
And what about other implementations such as LDK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the two implementations are perfectly interchangeable, as long as `bitcoin-cli` can talk to either Bitcoin core or Bitcoin knots it should just work as expected.

CLN internally actually calls out to `bitcoin-cli`, and needs only a handful methods are used anyway, so the difference between the two implementations may not even have any effect, as it affects parts we don't use internally.

I don't know the specifics of how ldk interacts with it's Bitcoin backend, and it may depend on which components you combine. I'd expect however that ldk would also not be affected by the switch in Bitcoin implementation.

Disclaimer: I am one of the CLN maintainers, hence the "we" in the reply.